# WiFi USB dongle that work

Tags: release-loki, wifi, kernel

After updating to kernel 4.4 my old realtek will not work anymore, so I tried wirh a TP-Link Archer TU1 but without success...  I would want to ask if exist a WiFi USB dongle that works out of the box with kernel >= 4.4?

Answer (score 1):

I have used the [Edimax EW-7811Un](https://amzn.com/B003MTTJOY) adapter with elementary OS. It is advertised as supporting Linux and is a popular choice for Raspberry Pi projects, which means it's nice and small, relatively inexpensive, and well-reviewed.